# Calculating sum of difference between multiple timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have a table that lists `playerID` along with a `startDate` and `endDate` column. These are timestamps.

e.g.

```
playerID    startDate               endDate
1           2017-06-01 12:00:00     2017-06-01 12:05:00 
1           2017-06-01 13:30:00     2017-06-01 13:33:00 
1           2017-08-04 14:57:00     0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I am trying to run a query to get the total number of seconds between the `startDate` and `endDate` for a specific player. If the `endDate` is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` then I should use the current time.

Here is what I have tried:

```
select
    IF(endDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, endDate) as finishDate, 
    sum((startDate-finishDate)) as timeTaken 
from table where playerID=1 group by playerID
```

This has two issues. I don't think I can use `finishDate` as I get an unknown column error. I also want the sum of all rows for playerID 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a handy function [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) which can calculate the difference between two timestamps in a variety of units, including seconds.  We can simply aggregate over each player and sum the diff of the starting and ending timetamps, using a `CASE` expression to replace the (somewhat odd) zero timestamp with the current timestamp.

```
SELECT
    playerID,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                      startDate,
                      CASE WHEN endDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                           THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ELSE endDate END)) AS timeTaken
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY playerID
```

Editorial: I don't know what `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is doing in your table but I would much rather use something like `NULL` to represent an end timestamp which is not known.  This would also make the code a bit nicer, e.g. we could use the following to check for an unknown end timestamp:

```
COALESCE(endDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```